# exclude a directory from Laravel mechanism and access the directory directly

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess

I have a website built on Laravel 9. Now for some reason, I need to add a folder/directory in the root (httpdocs) named "news".

When I go to my website e.g. mywebsite.com, Laravel website works fines as expected but when I go to mywebsite.com/news, the Laravel mechanism kicks in and shows an error page.

So my question is How can I make it (either through .htaccess or etc) so that Laravel does not get activated when I access the directory "news" and the contents inside "news"?

My .htaccess in **root** currently have this three lines

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
```

And .htaccess inside the **public** folder contains this -

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]   

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I am on the Apache Plesk server. *There are similar looking questions on StackOverflow but none mets my requirement*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
> ```

You can add another condition (`RewriteCond` directive) to the root `.htaccess` file to prevent the request being rewritten to the (Laravel) `/public` subdirectory. However, your existing condition is incorrect and will *always* be successful (although strictly speaking this is not necessary anyway - which is why it still "works" - since the presence of the `/public/.htaccess` file effectively prevents the rewrite loop). It should read `^/public` (with a slash), not `!^public`.

For example:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/news
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
```

The first *condition* is successful only when the `REQUEST_URI` variable (root relative URL-path) does not (`!`) start with `/news`.

The two conditions can be combined if you wish by changing the regex. ie. `!^/(public|news)`.

Alternatively, add the `news` directory in the `public` subdirectory (ie. `/public/news`) then you don't have to change either `.htaccess` file. (Although you should still "correct" the root `.htaccess` file as mentioned above.)

Answer (score 1):

Well, you implement an exception rule *before* the rules used by Laravel. Your rule in the "root" folder (I assume you refer to the folder configured as `DOCUMENT_ROOT` in your http server's host configuration) rewrites all incoming requests to the "public" folder. The rules implemented in there probably are maintained by Laravel? Again the last rule rewrites *all* requests to the controller.

So you want to implement an *exception* that prevents requests to `/news/...` to get rewritten to Laraval, right? Just add such a rule *prior* (so above) the existing rule currently rewriting everything to Laraval:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^news/ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
```

That additional rule will *not* rewrite requests to resources starting with a path `/path/`. Requests to `/path` (without trailing slash) will still get rewritten to `/public/news`.

Note that I also fixed the `RewriteCond`. You need to implement a pattern testing against the *absolut* requested path. That is explained in the documentation: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond

It is a good idea to test your implementation using a test tool, especially when you are still trying around. Have a try here:
https://htaccess.madewithlove.com?share=70cc8414-53ed-48cc-9dc8-758e0376c775

I personally would prefer to implement such general rules in the central http server's host configuration, not in a *distributed* configuration file (".htaccess") as you currently do. Various reasons for that. But maybe you do not have access to the actual, central configuration, for example if you are using a cheap hosting provider.